# Fractional quantum number induced in a soliton profile

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, experimental-physics, solitons, topological-field-theory

It has been known there is fractional quantum number induced in a soliton profile, such as [this Jeffrey Goldstone and Frank Wilczek paper](http://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.47.986) and many works of Jackiw.
For example the electric charge trapped at the soliton can have charge 1/2 e.

> Q: Are there experiments capturing this fractional quantum number induced in a soliton profile? What are they? (Ref are fine. But please be wisely chosen for experiments articles.)

such as in Polyacetylene, or like graphene device?